# System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: Sales

Tags: apex, unit-test, process-builder

I'm only getting this error in production.
When I perform the tests in STG it works normally.

Does anyone know the reason?

Error:

System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: Sales
Stack Trace: Class.LicenseCustomFieldUpdadeTest.versionLicenseCustomFieldUpdate: line 23, column 1

Just for the sake of knowledge this class is called by a Process Builder on the User Object.

```
public class LicenseCustomFieldUpdade {

//Updates a field that demonstrates whether or not the user has a Sales/Service/Partner license.

@InvocableMethod(label='Sales/Service/Partner Custom Field Updade')
public static void versionLicenseCustomFieldUpdate(list<Id> userIds){
           
    List<User> userlist = [Select Id, Sales_or_Service__c, UserPermissionsSupportUser, Salesforce_User_License__c from User where Id =:userIds];
    
    for(User aux : userlist){

        if( aux.Salesforce_User_License__c == 'Partner Community' ){

            aux.Sales_or_Service__c = 'Partner';
            
        }else if(aux.UserPermissionsSupportUser == false){
            
            aux.Sales_or_Service__c = 'Sales';
            
        }else{
            
            aux.Sales_or_Service__c = 'Service';
            
        }
        
    }
    
    if(!userlist.isEmpty()){
        
        update userlist;
        
    }
    
}
```

}

```
public class LicenseCustomFieldUpdadeTest {
    @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    static void versionLicenseCustomFieldUpdate(){
        User u = new user();
        u.LastName = 'Test Code';
        u.Email = 'test@test.com';
        u.Alias = 'Tcode';
        u.Username = 'hahahahahahaha@test.com';
        u.CommunityNickname = 'hahahahaha';
        u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT';
        u.ProfileID = '00ef4000000pu8E';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        u.UserPermissionsSupportUser = False;
        insert u;
        
        User aux = [SELECT ID,Sales_or_Service__c FROM USER WHERE id =:u.Id];
        
        System.assertEquals(aux.Sales_or_Service__c, 'Sales');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between these bits of code?  As it is, your `LicenseCustomFieldUpdade` class has nothing to do with your test class, so it could be as simple an issue as there is no default value for `Sales_or_Service__c` in production.  Please edit your question with more detail about how this code works and why you expect it to be working differently.

Comment: I found the mistake.

Comment: LicenseCustomFieldUpdade.versionLicenseCustomFieldUpdate(listaId);

Comment: Beginner - great that you found the answer; the way to do this is post an Answer then mark as accepted

Comment: Never write unit tests with `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`. Here, you don't need it, but it makes your tests fragile; tests should always create their own data.